# Regex for adjacent vowels and consonants?

Tags: regex

I want to write a PCRE-style regular expression that would match a sequence of three or more letters in which a vowel and consonant are adjacent.

So far I am needing to use two patterns, to account for the actual position of the two adjacent characters.

```php
/([aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]|[b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou])[a-z]/i
```

```php
/[a-z]([aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]|[b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou])/i
```

Any chance I am missing something, and that this can actually be done in just one expression?

Comment: Do you need to capture the 3 letters?  Or simply test whether or not such occurs in the string?

Comment: `/[a-z](?:([aeiou])([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])|(?2)(?1))/i`

Comment: @Wiktor great, this is shorter and works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following with PCRE:

```js
/[a-z](?:([aeiou])([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])|(?2)(?1))/i
```

Here, the consonant and vowel matching patterns are captured in their own groups and `(?1)` and `(?2)` are regex subroutines that recurse the corresponding group patterns without the need to repeat them.

Comment: I still have to use both expressions, placing `[a-z]` on either end, in order to match both "aab" and "baa". But this is shorter and more understandable. And combining the two expressions isn't a big deal from here.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(your first regex)|(your second regex)/i
```

If you are capturing the result, use [2] instead of [1] -- because of the extra parens.